# How can i customize cart page

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I want to change the looks of this cart page as well i want to add some other information. How can i achieve it?

[image]

Comment: Please add more information. How you want to move elements and change its looks?

Comment: Change Qty textbox to drop down, Remove summary block and put below all the product.